# Where can I find a proof of Thompson's Theorem regarding existence of disjoint cycles in graph with outward degree at least 3?

Tags: graph-theory, online-resources

I am looking for a proof of thompson's theorem: Given a directed graph with outward degree at least 3 for each vertex, there exist 2 vertex disjoint directed cycles. I can only find it behind a paywall here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579195 .

But it's from freaking 1984 so I hope there is a free proof.

Thanks

Comment: Thomassen     is the author.

Answer (score 1):

[This article does $k=3$ in the Bermond-Thomassen conjecture](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00487102/document), but also gives a stronger version of the 1983 result, $k=2, $ which gives you what you want.

There does not seem to be anyone involved named Thompson.

See
http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/the_bermond_thomassen_conjecture

Comment: Yup that's the guy, misread it for some reason. Thank you good, however it seems that in the paper you mentioned, when proving the stronger theorem they use the original theorem.